# How to generated web tier using Wicket with existing dao tier

Tags: java, wicket

I have created dao tier in my application. Now I want to generated web tier with basic crud operations in wicket. I read that apache ISIS can do this: http://isis.apache.org/. I successfully download and run their example and it look very good but I didnt find any tutorial how to replace their DAO tier with mine. So the question is how to replace it or is there better framework which can handle this task ?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Isis is a full-stack framework, so you don't really need to write your own DAO layer.  Instead, we leverage the JDO/DataNucleus ORM.  Annotate your pojos and the ORM will do its thing.

The only persistence layer stuff you do need to write is specific implementations of your repositories, to use JDO queries.  The example archetype that you have already tried out has an example of this.

If you have an existing database schema, you can adapt the JDO/DN ObjectStore to use it by using good old fashioned SQL views.  For any non-updateable views, you can install "instead of" triggers.  In fact, I'd argue this is good practice even for green-field projects.

Comment: hm problem is I want to create DAO layer just by own because I am using another framework which generate it (sql processor) and I  want to generate just web tier